# Sum the cells that have a color fill to them in a set range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I would very much like to know if there is a function that can sum up the cells that are 'colored only, in a range.

For example: I have a range of number in cells f1:f30  some cells have a color fill to them (doesn't matter what color) and others don't.
How do I sum only the ones with color?

Comment: how were the cells colored, manually or using conditional formatting. if using conditional formatting it can be done. see this from more info...http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/conditional-formatting-tricks-sum-values-in-excel-by-cell-color/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround, use a formula such as:

```
=SUM(F1:F30)-SUBTOTAL(109,F1:F30)
```

in F32, filter rows 1:30 and for ColumnF select Filter by Color, No Fill.